# Pygame surface to opencv image object (not file saving)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pygame

I have a rectangle area on a pygame surface. I want to convert that area into an opencv image object (without saving to file) for further image processing on that rectangle area only. How can I do that?

```
selected_area =  mysurface.subsurface((x,y,w,h))
img_array=numpy.array(pygame.surfarray.array2d(selected_area))

#image_object = ..... ?

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_object, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("test",gray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a *cv2* image is just a three-dimensional *numpy* array. the 1st dimension is the height, the 2nd the width and the 3rd the number of channels in the order blue, green, red.
Use [`pygame.surfarray.pixels3d`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels3d) to reference pixels into a 3d array:

```py
img_array = numpy.array(pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(selected_area))
```

Unfortunately, the pixels are stored in row mayor order. The color channels are in the order red, green, blue. So you need to reformat this array. [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the array:

```py
image_object = numpy.transpose(img_array, (1, 0, 2))
```

Finally swap the red and blue color channel with either

```py
image_object[:, :, [0, 2]] = image_object[:, :, [2, 0]]
```

or

```py
image_object = cv2.cvtColor(image_object, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Convert function:

```py
def pygameSurfaceToCv2Image(mysurface, x, y, w, h):
    selected_area =  mysurface.subsurface((x, y, w, h))
    img_array = numpy.array(pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(selected_area))
    image_object = numpy.transpose(img_array, (1, 0, 2))
    image_object[:, :, [0, 2]] = image_object[:, :, [2, 0]]
    return image_object
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import cv2, numpy

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def pygameSurfaceToCv2Image(mysurface, x, y, w, h):
    selected_area =  mysurface.subsurface((x, y, w, h))
    img_array = numpy.array(pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(selected_area))
    image_object = numpy.transpose(img_array, (1, 0, 2))
    #image_object[:, :, [0, 2]] = image_object[:, :, [2, 0]]
    image_object = cv2.cvtColor(image_object, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return image_object

apple_surf = pygame.image.load("Apple1.bmp")
image_object = pygameSurfaceToCv2Image(apple_surf, 20, 20, 200, 120)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_object, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("apple subsurface", image_object)
cv2.imshow("gray apple subsurface", gray)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```